# SOAP call returning HTML in JavaScript but returns XML with SOAP UI

Tags: angular, xml, soap

I implemented a basic SOAP call for a get request. For this I tested the entry point in SOAP UI in order to have required informations. This code is implemented in an Angular 12 component that uses a service layer.

[image]

At this stage i have the enveloppe for my call and the response.
Now I try to implement this stuff in javaScript. I have a service layer where i set the XMLHttpRequest. Note : I also use a proxy, that's why my call is on localhost:4300...

```
public soapCall() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4300/WS/GetCategories.fsp', true);

  // build SOAP request
  var sr =
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
    'xmlns:bran="http://www.bottomline.com/soap/branch/"> ' +
    '<soapenv:Header/> ' +
    '<soapenv:Body> ' +
    '<bran:CallBranch soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/> ' +
    '</soapenv:Body> ' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  // Send the request
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  let map = new Map();
  map.set("xhr", xhr);
  map.set("sr", sr);
  return map;
  // xhr.send(sr);
}
```

Finally in my component, I make a call:

```
soapCall() {
  let map = this.soapService.anotherCall()
  let xhr = map.get('xhr');
  let str = map.get('sr')
  xhr.send(str);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        // alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(str)
}
```

The printing result is not really what i expect. It returns HTML that contains the XML. As a matter of fact I had the same issue by using a classic REST call...

[image]

Comment: SOAP works over POST not GET. If the service is implemented over GET, then that's not a proper SOAP web service but some RPC API that deals in XML messages that look like SOAP messages. Also, you say you are using a proxy. What is this proxy? Is it possible it adds the extra stuff around the response? Can't you just call the service directly?

Comment: i replace the get with a post call and i obtain the correct response ! the proxy is used to solve locally CORS issues. I also replaced :  xhr.responseText by xhr.responseText.replace(/&quot;/g, '\" thanks !